# Is vector W in the span of V1,V2,V3

Tags: linear-algebra

1. $v_1=(1,1,0)$
2. $v_2=(1,2,1)$
3. $v_3=(1,3,2)$
4. $w=(2,1,-1)$

Is $w$ in $span(v_1,v_2,v_3)$?

Comment: To solve this problem, you need to find scalars $c_{1}, c_{2}$, and $c_{3}$ such that $c_{1}v_{1} + c_{2}v_{2} + c_{3}v_{3} = w$.  If these scalars don't exist, then $w$ is **not** in the span of the three vectors.  Do you have any inclination as to how we would check if these scalars exist?

Answer (score 2):

Given $v_1=(1,1,0)^{\top}$, $v_2=(1,2,1)^{\top}$, $v_3=(1,3,2)^{\top}$, $w=(2,1,-1)^{\top}$

If $w \in span\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$, then there are constants $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that $w = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + c_3v_3$. That is,
$$[v_1\quad v_2 \quad v_3][c_1 \; c_2 \; c_3]^{\top} = w$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\
1&2&3\\
0&1&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\
c_2\\
c_3\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\
1\\
-1\end{pmatrix}$$

If there is a non-zero solution to this linear system, then w belongs to the span.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. By inspection, observe that $w = 3v_1 - v_2$.

In general, this can be determined by forming an augmented system and using Gaussian Elimination.

Answer (score 1):

Form a matrix and reduce: iff the row formed by $\;w\;$ vanishes the answer to your question is yes:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\
1&2&1\\
1&3&2\\
2&1&-1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&2&2\\
0&-1&-1\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\
0&1&1\\
0&0&0\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus the answer is yes...and btw, only the first two vectors $\;v_1,v_2\;$ are enough to form $\;Span\,\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\;$

Answer (score 0):

You can easily verify that $v_1, v_2, v_3$  are linearly dependent, since their determinant is $0$.

Thus, you have that $\langle v_1,v_2,v_3\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ and $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent.

Also, you can easily verify that  $v_1,v_2,w$ are linearly dependent, by checking the $3\times 3$ determinant, which is $0$.

So, $w$ can be written as a linear combination of $v_1, v_2$.